# Using a data access layer calling method on different page wont update database

Tags: c#, database, data-access-layer

I have a data access layer to update and trying to call method on different page wont update database

i have tried moving some code around to be outside of the loop and also set a break point but the data doesn't reach the break point

Data access layer code (DAL):

```
public void editBuyerByID(int bID, string title, string fname, string lname, string email, string pWord, string tel,string pCode, double price, string type)
{
  using (var context = dc)
  {
    Buyer editBuyer = (from b in context.Buyers where b.BuyerID == bID select b).FirstOrDefault();

    if (editBuyer != null)
      {
        editBuyer.BuyerTitle = title;
        editBuyer.BuyerFName = fname;
        editBuyer.BuyerLName = lname;
        editBuyer.BuyerEmail = email;
        editBuyer.BuyerPassword = pWord;
        editBuyer.BuyerTelNo = tel;
        editBuyer.BuyerPostcode = pCode;
        editBuyer.BuyerPriceRange = price;
        editBuyer.BuyerType = type;

        //context.Buyers.Add(editBuyer);
        context.SaveChanges();

      }
    }
}
```

Account Page where method being called:

```
   protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                aDal.editBuyerByID(Convert.ToInt32(Session["Buyer"].ToString()),
                                            txtTitle.Text, txtFName.Text, txtLName.Text,
                                            txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtTelNo.Text, txtPostcode.Text, Convert.ToSingle(txtPrice.Text), txtType.Text);
                string editBuyerScript = "alert(\"Your details have been updated\");";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                      "ServerControlScript", editBuyerScript, true);
            }
            catch
            {
                string invalidScript = "alert(\"All fields must be filled correctly\");";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                      "ServerControlScript", invalidScript, true);
            }



        }
```

Comment: since you are working in C# (an object oriented programming language), you could pass the Buyer details to _editBuyerByID_ method with a _Buyer_ class object instead of a long list of fields!

Comment: how would i go about doing this?

Comment: any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: do you encounter with any error, if yes what is the error message?

Comment: no its just that it doesn't update in the database the message comes up that updated successfully but when checked it hasn't

Comment: which version of entity framework you are using?

Comment: try adding this line of code `context.Entry(editBuyer).State = EntityState.Modified;` before `context.SaveChanges();` in DAL function.

Comment: How would I do it through a class I have a buyer class but am unsure how to go about it

Comment: I can write code for you to use Buyer class, but I would have to add an answer for that!

Comment: It comes up error saying cannot implicitly convert system.data.entitystate to system.data.entity.ebtitystate.. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that but any help would be appreciated

Comment: also adding this code doesnt work it does nothing : context.Entry(editBuyer).State = EntityState.Modified; before context.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

in your DAL, `editBuyerByID` method could receive the changed Buyer object instead of a set of fields, in the method just mark the entity as changed and save changes:

```
public void editBuyerByID(Buyer buyer)
{
  using (var context = dc)
  {
    context.Entry(buyer).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

and in the `btnUpdate_Click` event make the following changes, get the buyer object (assuming you have method to get buyer by ID in the DAL), update fields and send to the `editBuyerByID` DAL method:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    int buyerId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Buyer"].ToString());
    Buyer buyer = aDal.getBuyerByID(buyerId);

      if(buyer!=null) 
      {
        buyer.BuyerTitle = txtTitle.Text;
        buyer.BuyerFName = txtFName.Text;
        buyer.BuyerLName = txtLName.Text;
        buyer.BuyerEmail = txtEmail.Text;
        buyer.BuyerPassword = txtPassword.Text;
        buyer.BuyerTelNo = txtTelNo.Text;
        buyer.BuyerPostcode = txtPostcode.Text;
        buyer.BuyerPriceRange = Convert.ToSingle(txtPrice.Text);
        buyer.BuyerType = txtType.Text;

        aDal.editBuyerByID(buyer);
      }

      string editBuyerScript = "alert(\"Your details have been updated\");";
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", editBuyerScript, true);
  }
  catch
  {
    string invalidScript = "alert(\"All fields must be filled correctly\");";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", invalidScript, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont have the method to get the buyer id only a list of buyers

Comment: i have this code in DAL im not sure if its the same thing you mean :
   public Buyer findBuyerByID(int ID)
        {

            using (var context = new DBModel())
            {
                Buyer findBuyer = (from b in context.Buyers
                                   where b.BuyerID == ID
                                   select b).FirstOrDefault();

                return findBuyer;

            }
        }

Comment: Any help would be appreciated